# Is the sentence idiomatice

Tags: grammaticality

"The organizations ,x,y and z
, engage in the race to becoming the leading producer in the contry."

Is the above sentence idiomatic?

Comment: This is Off Topic proofreading. But briefly - 1: you don't want commas before or after ***a, y, and z*** (note that we always include a space after a comma). 2: Present Continuous ***are engaged** in **a** race* is better than Simple Present ***engage***. 3: You must use the *infinitive* verb form in *...a race **to become** the leading producer*. And you spelt ***country*** wrong.

Comment: The x, y and z organizations are engaged in a race to become the leading producer [?] in the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *the race to* is usually followed by a base verb, not an *-ing* form.

Secondly, the simple present would not be used here,

So the following is the closest to your suggestion that is possible.

> "The organizations ,x,y and z are engaged in the race to become the leading producer in the country."

but I would expect to see something like

> The organizations ,x,y and z are vying to become the leading producer in the country."

Comment: If i say "race for becoming leading producer in country".Then i think it will be idiomatic

Comment: No it won't. _For_ does not generally collocate with _race_, and if it does, it does not indicate the goal, but who the possible contestants are. eg. _A race for two-year olds_ (in the context of horse racing).